# Java reading multiple variable from a single line, but how to terminate using one variable?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = br.nextInt();
int b = br.nextInt();
int c = br.nextInt();
```

If I only want to enter a single value, for example "0" to terminate the program, how do I do that? Because with the code above you have to enter 3 values, right?

Comment: if ( a == 0 ) { System.exit(0); } it'll never even reach the line after that. but the a, b, c values are not read from a single line, if that is what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a while loop, and a list to store the data.

```
boolean mustContinue = true;
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(mustContinue) {
    Integer a = br.nextInt();
    if(a == 0) {
        mustContinue = false;
    } else {
        result.add(a);
    }
}
```

This is not a complete running code, it's just to give you an idea of a possible solution. There are some thing to care of in order to make it a complete running code (for example check `br.hasNextInt()` to prevent exception, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a while loop, it will end when you type 0:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    while (sc.hasNextInt() && ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 0))
    {
        // do something
    }
```